# Adding product to blog sidebar

Tags: commerce

In Drupal 8 commerce 2, how would I embed a product with an add to cart button and select ID of my choosing into the sidebar of a blog post?

Comment: I don't understand why this has been voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done please see this issue from drupal.org
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2935377